# How to call a method from another class, in a class in Java

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to use a method I've created in class `Student`, in another class, `Classroom`.  I'm wondering if it is even possible to call a method that's defined in another class, or if I'm approaching this the wrong way.

class`Student`:

```
public class Student {
    String firstName;

    Student(String firstName){
        this.firstName=firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

class `Classroom`:

```
public class Classroom{

    public ArrayList<Student> students;

    public Classroom(ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList) {

    }

    Student getStudent(ArrayList students){
        this.students=students;
        System.out.println(students.get(0).getFirstName);
        return null;
    }
}
```

`Main`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student a = new Student("John");
        Student b = new Student("Jane");

        ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = null;
        studentArrayList.add(a);
        studentArrayList.add(b);

        Classroom c = new Classroom(studentArrayList);

        System.out.println(c.getStudent(studentArrayList));
    }
}
```

My problem seems to be when I attempt to call the method `getFirstName`, I'm wondering is there is a way to call `getFirstName` in the `Classroom` class.  My intention for this code is to return the object `a`.

Comment: `students.get(0).getFirstName` you're missing `()` after `getFirstName`, however in your particular case you shouldn't pass it an `ArrayList` as parameter, but the index, and would call your name as `getStudentName(int index) { students.get(index).getFirstName() }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you forgot to put parentheses after `getFirstName()` in the `Classroom` class, also, you should initialize `students` in the constructor.

Here's what it should look like:

```java
public class Classroom {

    public ArrayList<Student> students;

    public Classroom(ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList) {
        students = studentArrayList
        // you can add other code here
    }

    Student getStudent(int index) {
        // get the first name of the student at the given index
        System.out.println(students.get(index).getFirstName());
        return students.get(index); // return the Student object instead of null
    }
}
```

Then, inside the `Main` class:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student a = new Student("John");
        Student b = new Student("Jane");

        ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studentArrayList.add(a);
        studentArrayList.add(b);

        Classroom c = new Classroom(studentArrayList); // now the students ArrayList is initialized

        System.out.println(c.getStudent(0)); // replace 0 with the index you want
    }
}
```

You can keep the `Student` class as is.

Answer (score 2):

`students.get(0).getFirstName` is a field.

To call the method just add parentheses - `students.get(0).getFirstName()`